# Reverse string and print it in assembly MIPS language

Tags: assembly, mips

I am trying here to reverse this string and I am really stuck.

I take the string from variable letter and length throw the code, send them to reversing_loop and do as in the code, if counter reaches the same as length go to Exit and print the result I am not even sure about this two lines

```
sw $a2, result
la $a0 , $a2
```

Here is the code:

```
.data

letters: .asciiz "abcd"
result: .asciiz ""

.text

.globl main
main:
la $a0, letters    # reading chars letters
li $a1, 4     # store length
li $a3, 0          # counter
add $a0, $a0, $a1  # address of last char

reversing_loop:
beq $a3, $a1, Exit
lb $t0,($a0)
sb $t0,($a2)
addi $a0,$a0, -1   # i -=1
addi $a2,$a2, 1  # move address
addi $a3, $a3, 1 # increment counter
j reversing_loop

Exit:
sw $a2, result
la $a0 , $a2
li $v0 , 4
syscall
li $v0 , 10
syscall

.end main
```

Comment: You've only reserved space for a single byte (the null-terminator) at `result`.

Comment: Also, how can you write to `($a2)` inside the `reversing_loop` when you haven't initialized `$a2` at that point?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this syntax, so just out of curiosity, if I wanted to reserve space (for example) for 19 characters + null terminator, I would do this: ```result: word 0,0,0,0,0```

Answer (score 0):

I finally finished the code and it runs correctly.

```
.data

letters: .byte 'a','b','c','d','e'
result: .asciiz ""

.text

.globl main
main:
la $a0, letters    # reading chars letters
li $a1, 5          # store length
la $a2 , result        # intialize a2
li $a3, 0          # counter
addi $a0, $a0, 4  # address of last char

reversing_loop:
beq $a3, $a1, Exit
lb $t0, 0($a0)
sb $t0, 0($a2)
addi $a0,$a0, -1   # i -=1
addi $a2,$a2, 1  # move address
addi $a3, $a3, 1 # increment counter
j reversing_loop

Exit:
addi $a2,$a2,-5
add $a0,$0, $a2

li $v0 , 4
syscall
li $v0 , 10
syscall

.end main
```